# Create a PDF image by adding several PDF images to the same blank page

Tags: windows, pdf, image-editing, vector-graphics, image-formats

I have several images with the extension `.pdf`, and I want to create a new PDF image (large figure) out of them. Also, I want to add some geometric shapes and text boxes to the same figure. How can I do that?

P.S. These images are figures I exported as PDF files to have vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You may do that as follows:

1. Get a good PDF editor (for example Adobe Acrobat Pro)
2. Open all four PDFs
3. Create new blank PDF
4. Copy and paste the figures from the four PDFs to the new one
5. Save As the new PDF.